# Launching messaging-simulator and auto app in android

Tags: android, apk, android-auto

I wanted to test android auto sample (Hello World notification) app given in developer guide samples.

I followed the steps - https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html

Tried launching messaging simulator and then, waiting for "Hello World" notification on auto simulator (messaging-simulator app). But nothing appeared. Should I look into messaging/inbox folder? tried restarting as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it! Its a Messaging Sample App which will be launched in Android Fragment. Also, if the app doesn't launch yet, stop the simulator from Settings > Apps then restart it.